# page didvision with css

Tags: css

I have divided my page into three sections: left, center, and right. Elements supposed to appear in the center are under `class="center"` and those to appear in the right are under `class="right"`. But for some reason when I run this code

```
<div id="center">
  <div>Hello world </div>
  <div><label>Name</label> <input type="text" name="fnam" class="fields" id="fn" /></div>
</div>
```

the output come out as:

```
   Hello
   world
   Name 
   field(text input)
```

Whenever there is a space between elements the following elements appear on the next line. It does the same for class="right" too. The CSS code for `.center` and `.right`:

```
#right{
  position : absolute;
  right:500px;
  margin-top :-75px;
  width : 160px;
  padding : 3px;

}
#center {
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see all of your code - at least left, center, right CSS and a little HTML (is there a wrap? is the wrap using position:relative?). Right now I can only guess as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## leftDiv

{
width:24%;
min-height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
}

## centerDiv

{
width:50%;
float:left;
min-height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
margin-left:10px;
}

## rightDiv

{
width:24%;
float:left;
min-height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
margin-left:10px;
}

```
<div id="leftDiv"></div>
<div id="centerDiv"></div>
<div id="rightDiv"></div>
```